# Skip API calls on tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I make API calls when create a user but I don't want do this calls on test environment.

What do you do with on this situations? I have external APIs like Mailchimp and internal APIs to communicate with others apps, how do you to test or not this APIs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mocking API is the purpose of fakeweb presented [in this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/276-testing-time-web-requests).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to mock your API calls then using some [mocking libraries for Ruby](http://pathfindersoftware.com/2009/05/comparing-ruby-mock-object-libraries/).